# Open a Watcom DB with C#

Tags: c#, database, watcom

So, I was just asked if I can open a watcom db file through C# as we need to retrieve some data from it, and neither Access nor Sql Server appear capable of importing it.

I don't know where to begin...

All I've been given is a .DB file, and those vague instructions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll likely need to contact Sybase and ask for an ODBC driver for it. With that, you will be able to open the database using ODBC database calls.

See these threads for more info:

[Import Watcom db into SQL](http://www.sqlnewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.sqlserver.server/topic21307.aspx)

[Is there a Watcom ODBC driver?](http://groups.google.com/group/sybase.public.connectivity.odbc/browse_thread/thread/aa20c88a7d9613e3?pli=1)